# ENOTDIR error on npm install (npm 3 over node 4. I know: legacy. Sorry :( )

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm

First of all, my apologies for reporting a problem of npm3 here, but it looks like the old repo is currently in read only mode.

We have a big and old angularjs frontend app, that requires node4 and uses npm3. A couple of days ago, a problem raised when someone performed a npm install.

error

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.19.0-13-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqq/abc-batch-qqq/node/node" "/home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqq/abc-batch-qqq/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqq/abc-batch-qqq/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-69b48d6f/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! errno -20
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqq/abc-batch-qqq/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-69b48d6f/package.json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for abc",
  "private": true,
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/main/webapp/bower_components"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "1.7.9",
    "browser-sync": "2.12.10",
    "del": "2.2.1",
    "eslint-config-angular": "0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "1.3.1",
    "event-stream": "3.3.4",
    "generator-jhipster": "3.4.2",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "1.1.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-changed": "1.3.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "2.1.2",
    "gulp-eslint": "3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "0.3.0",
    "gulp-footer": "1.0.5",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "2.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "3.0.2",
    "gulp-inject": "4.1.0",
    "gulp-natural-sort": "0.1.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "2.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-constant": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-notify": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "7.1.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "0.4.3",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.5.4",
    "gulp-useref": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "karma": "1.1.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-script-launcher": "1.0.0",
    "lazypipe": "1.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.14.0",
    "main-bower-files": "2.13.1",
    "map-stream": "0.0.6",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.9",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "xml2js": "0.4.16",
    "yargs": "4.8.1",
    "useref": "1.4.1",
    "esquery": "1.0.1"
   },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  }
}
```

npm-debug

```
warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
150443 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
150444 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
150444 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
150444 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   linux
150444 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
150445 warn node-fetch@2.6.7 requires a peer of encoding@^0.1.0 but none was installed.
150446 verbose If you need help, you may report this error at:
150446 verbose     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
150447 verbose stack Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqqq/abc-batch-qqqq/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-69b48d6f/package.json'
150447 verbose stack     at Error (native)
150448 verbose cwd /home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqqq/abc-batch-qqqq
150449 error Linux 4.19.0-13-amd64
150450 error argv "/home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqqq/abc-batch-qqqq/node/node" "/home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqqq/abc-batch-qqqq/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install"
150451 error node v4.4.3
150452 error npm  v3.10.10
150453 error path /home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqqq/abc-batch-qqqq/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-69b48d6f/package.json
150454 error code ENOTDIR
150455 error errno -20
150456 error syscall open
150457 error ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqqq/abc-batch-qqqq/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-69b48d6f/package.json'
150458 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
150458 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
150459 verbose exit [ -20, true ]
```

I cannot upgrade to newer npm versions, because of the angularjs app and dependencies. I tried to move to npm6, but the application also packaging stopped working

Anyone have any clues about this? I'm completely desperated...

Thanks in advance and sorry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem!

It is related with the library generator-jhipster (or any of its dependencies)

We don't use it anymore, so i got rid of it and everything works again!

Thanks everybody!

Comment: I've experienced the same issue, but here it was because of @azure/storage-file-datalake
Updating the dependency fixed the issue

Comment: Did you discover this through trial-and-error @Bringer? Or were you able to analyse the logs to figure out it was `generator-jhipster`? We have an almost-identical problem with a legacy app, but we’re not using that specific library.

Comment: I compared two jenkins executions: one with a failure and one with a success. The error rised by the library deasync . Looking in the library hierachy, it was provided by generator-jhipster and we don't need it anymore, so i got rid of it.

Comment: Thank you. For the record, in our app the problem was `@airbrake/browser`.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the issue. It's because there's a file called tmp in the home directory.

```
rm -rf ~/tmp
sudo npm cache clear
sudo npm install -g node
```

Also... if you are trying to install npm then the same error and solution applies - delete ~/tmp

Comment: Hi @yanir thanks a lot for your response. unfortunately, your solution doesn't work for me :\

Same error, again

```
workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqqq/abc-batch-qqqq/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-69b48d6f/package.json
150454 error code ENOTDIR
150455 error errno -20
150456 error syscall open
150457 error ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/home/pparker/workspaces/eclipse/abc/abc_refactor/abc_qqqq/abc-batch-qqqq/node_modules/.staging/@types/node-69b48d6f/package.json'


```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to a library with an incorrect/incompatible version on your package.json file. I've had the same issue in the past, and in my case, it was caused by `browser-sync`.

To check if this is your case, you can change your package.json file, removing the libraries line by line (or, "grouping" them and removing group by group), and run the install command to see if the installation works properly.

The expected results are that after removing the problematic library, the install command should work.

After identifying it, you can try downgrading it to a version that worked with your project before.